# Running servlet on free host

Tags: java, servlets, server

I have developed a servlet locally. At this point, what I would like to do is to run it online. For this reason I've uploaded it on a free hosting. I call the HTML page containing a form, but at the time of the "action" I get a 404.

My question is: do I have to change the configuration of the `web.xml` file to run it? Or, do I have to change any other parameters?

Comment: A servlet needs to be compiled and deployed in a servlet container (e.g. tomcat) or application server (e.g. wildfly). I suspect you have some free webspace that lets you host files (such as html), but not a java servlet. How did you deploy your project?

Comment: You didn't give us enough information. First of all, check at least if you can run your servlet on locally installed Java servlet container. Once you succeed and the same steps will wont't get you anywhere (note that not all hostings let you run Java, as already been said), then come back and update the question with relevant details.

Comment: Locally I've compiled the servlet , then manually I've inserted the mapping in the web.xml..

Comment: probably the matter is simply that the host deny the java execution..

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatting.